# Is there a function to search for partial text in cells

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a function that searches a spreadsheet for a name I put in cell A1 and returns a column in that row
eg, if I enter Smith in A1 it will return all columns C´s where Column D contains Smith, I would also like it to return columns containing smith so if a cell as john smith it would also be returned,
this is what I have so far but it only returns Total match, 
=FILTER(Results!C:C,Results!$D:$D=$A$1)
Hope someone can help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
=filter(Results!C:C,find(lower($A$1),lower(Results!D:D))>=0)
```

[image]

EDIT: adding the `lower()` function to make the comparison case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks, Benoît Wéry This does work the only problem is it appears to look for exact matches ie if SMITH as been imputed in  higher case and the name you put in A1 is not then it will not find it, is there a way to make this not case sensitive,

Comment: Sure, just by comparing the lowercase versions of all values, see edited formula above.